# Trying to set a Jquery mobile page from a PHP GET variable

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

Hi folks this is driving me crazy so please help.

I am trying to create my first mobile app using Jquery Mobile.

I have 4 pages in my script i.e.

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">...Page code...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="services">...Page code...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="videos">...Page code...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="blog">...Page code...</div>
```

Within my videos page I have a number of list items with url links to the same url with the GET parameter of ID= for the video ID i.e.

```
<li><a href="test.php?videoID=1"</a></li>
```

When the link is clicked I want to use the videoID within the videos page, but the link sends me back to the home page, and if I then click through to the videos page the videoID is lost.

How can I get straight to the video page and be able to use the videoID?

Ideally looking for a mainly php based solution, as I am quite new to jquery.

Comment: *In a nutshell* `if(isset($_GET['videoID']) && $_GET['videoID'] == 1){ $video = $_GET['videoID'];} echo $video;`

Comment: Sorry I understand how to attach the GET value to a variable, the bit I can't seem to do is reach the #videos page with the variable in place.

Comment: If you're solely relying on an "id" in your div's, then you'll need to use Ajax/JS.

Answer (score 0):

First, grab the VideoID from the URL, as follows:

```
if (isset($_GET['videoID'])){
$myvideo=$_GET['videoID'];
//if you want to echo the result, you can do that, i.e: echo $myvideo;
//........... your next action after getting the video ID here .........
}
```

For example:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tablevideo WHERE videoID='$myvideo'";
........................ and so on ........
```

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question I am able to grab the videoID from the URL no problem. The issue I have is that the initial url is taking me back to the home page, not the video page. If I want to go straight to back to the video page but with the GET parameter still set, so something like test.php#videos?videoID=1 or test.php?videoID=1#videos, but neither of these work with the link

Comment: do you think anything wrong with the codes of yours or something has been wrong, say, url redirect setting? let me see your site to check for details

Comment: thanks, site is www.fcsexcel.com/mobileTest.php, there are some collapsible lists on the videos page, each link inside contains the id for a separate video. When I click on the video link, I want it to return me to the video page with the ID in the GET

Comment: well, pls check your redirect in cpanel or htaccess, I see everything is okay

Comment: Thanks for helping, I have managed to solve it now by using the ID to change the scr attribute of an iframe player and load the videos whilst on the page

Comment: yes, I guess the problem could be the iframe. I also try to type a link inside an iframe. Then I click it and I see the site appears inside the iframe, not out of the page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<li><a href="test.php?videoID=1">link text</a></li>
```

You could use a data-attribute:

```
<li><a href="#" data-videoid="1" class="vidLink" >link text</a></li>
```

Then you can add a click handler, which retrieves the videoid from the data attribute and make an AJAX call to your php to get the video:

```
$(document).on("click", ".vidLink", function(){
    var vidID = $(this).jqmData("videoid");
    //make AJAX call with ID to php to get the video
});
```